# Calculating the Fourier series for the function $y = 1,-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$.

Tags: fourier-series

Calculating the Fourier series for the function $y = 1,-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$.

**My answer:**

I have calculated it and I got $a_{0} = 2, a_{m} = b_{m} = 0.$ so the Fourier series of 1 is 1.
Am I correct?

Comment: 1=1 seems correct! And yes, your calculations are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your calculations are correct.